# Sci-fi texts used as part of school English class set around space corps

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to identify a series of science fiction texts I read as a child. They were used as part of English classes, specifically English language comprehension, basically reading the passage and answering questions relating to the content of what was read and so appeared in a text book with mutiple short stories and extracts of stories. This means I cannot be sure if I read a whole story or simply extracts of a larger piece.

These stories were read in the early 1980s at a UK primary school in the north of England. I mention location as different schools in different regions of the UK probably used different books. It is probable that the book was published in 1970's.

The details I remember are very vague and I may be conflating several unrelated works. The stories featured a space corp of some type, with a male  captain or a pilot as a prominent character. I have a very vague memory that characters may have been colour coded in a similar way to Captain Scarlet or that a prominent character had a name that was a colour for example Captain Black.

A feature of the final story (or at least the final story I recall) was that there were crystals that may have controlled time and possibly space ships too. The most vivid detail I recall was the shock ending of this story in which the main character died.  It was mentioned that he controlled lots of crystals but they had somehow escaped his control. A secondary character complains that he is "only able to control a small number of crystals".

There was a scene describing the central character decending on a rope or a winch from one spaceship to another to try and regain control of it. He manages after several attempts but a great personal cost. Another character, finds him at the controls of this spaceship and says something along the lines of "You look just like my father", the implication is that he has died of old age.